# Jquery date time picker not working in popup window

Tags: jquery, popup, datetimepicker

Here is my case: I use jquery datetimepicker and it works fine in normal page but it's not working in popup-page. This is the date field:

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $( "#date" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
```

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/nhonduyen/YqLk8/
You see the datetimepicker in body tag works, but when you click on contact -> schedule a meeting then a popup shows up, but the field datetimepicker doesn't work.
Can you help me?
Thank you. :)

Comment: Can you provide the full code of it. the jsfiddle just has the datepicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have use `id='date'` for more than one `date` field several times but `id` must be unique, So just change `id='date'` to `class='date'` and also in your `JavaScript` use:

```
$(".date").datepicker();
```

Instead of :

```
$("#date").datepicker();
```

It'll work ([Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YqLk8/3/)).

Answer (score 0):

It is conflict of datetimepicker source file version with bootstrap 4. use

[enter link description here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Date-Time-Picker-Bootstrap-4/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js)